# Ajax based micropost's comments (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, comments

I have ajax based micropost's comments on the user page. It works, but not correctly. When I submit a new comment to **any** micropost, it always posts to the **last** micropost. Then, if I refresh the page by "F5", everything falls into place - the new comment is in the correct micropost. Thanks in advance.

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :comment_content
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :micropost
end
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

   def create
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.micropost = @micropost
    @comment.user = current_user
      respond_to do |format|
      @comment.save
           format.html { redirect_to current_user }
           format.js
      end
   end 
end
```

**_micropost.html.erb**

```
<tr>
  <td class="micropost">
    <span class="content"><%= wrap(micropost.content) %></span>
    <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
    </span>
    <%= render 'shared/comment_form', micropost: micropost %>
   <div id="comments">
     <%= render micropost.comments %>
   </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**_comment_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for ([micropost, @comment]), :remote => true do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
<%= f.text_area :comment_content, :size => "40x2" %>
  <button class="btn" type="submit">
    Comment
  </button>
<% end %>
```

**_comment.html.erb**

```
<span style="width: 100%; background:#dff0d8"><%= wrap(comment.comment_content) %></span>
<span class="timestamp">
 Posted by <%= comment.user.name %> <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago.
</span>
```

**create.js.erb**

```
$('#comments').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @micropost.comments)) %>");
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Have you some error ?

Comment: There is no error, but comments posts only to the last micropost.

Comment: How if your view calling your JS ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've found it, I call JS with <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %> in _stylesheets.html.erb   In application.html.erb I have: <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change

```
@comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
@comment.micropost = @micropost
```

to

```
@comment = @micropost.comments.build(params[:comment])
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is the same problem.